# ADT Eclipse SDK troubles - No DDMS found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Please help me, I'm having serious trobules with Eclipse for the second time.
I'm following a guide and in these last days my Eclipse used to work fine (and was heavy 600 mb), now after the updates I did recommended by the guided, it downloaded a lot of things for hours and my folder now is 12.6 GBs (and it's pretty uncofortable since I'm on a not too large SSD).

The problem is that the old ADT worked, after the update every project gives errors, like there is no Android SDK.

The console gives me this error

```
[2014-11-18 22:37:33 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Users\Ruggiero\Desktop\Ruggiero\android_dev_environment\sdk\tools\hprof-conv.exe
```

If it can help you, when I run Eclipse it shows me this error message

[image: error]

Now, the most obvious thing would be "just press Check for updates".

When I do it, it says me there are no updates.
So I go for "Install new software" and after I go to the link (official Google link) and try to install the updates it gives me this error

[error2 http://s7.postimg.org/h5r1gaa63/eclipseerror2.png]](http://s7.postimg.org/h5r1gaa63/eclipseerror2.png])

Please do not flag as duplicate as I already searched on the web and StackOverflow too and even if I found similar troubles, no one was equal or really close to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I self resolved by switching to Android Studio IDE

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The only way I could make it work was to completely uninstall Eclipse and Android SDK and reinstall again.

Comment: I already did this and for the second time after updates it was unusuable, if I won't solve I'm gonna switch to Android Studio forever. I always preferred Eclipse for stability

Answer (score 0):

There are likely workarounds for this, but I think I suggest just downloading a fresh Android bundle (with all the correct updated software), and install it fresh.

I have had experiences where something goes wrong in the tools update, and found the simplest way to correct is to uninstall my existing tools and start fresh.  It is easy to install the bundle, and you will know you have all the correct packages and software installed.

You will spend a bit of time trying to debug your install, it will be quicker to install a fresh instance.

Comment: I think I will this but I'm really disappointed by all this inefficiency. I don't have a good connection and every time it takes a lot for downloading SDK upgrades. I'm going to switch to Android Studio and see if it doesn't break up everything after updates

Comment: I don't know if I improved or not situation, I copied DDMS files from old sdk folder, now it just doesn't recognize android SDK ("just"), so gives error on every class, is there a way to resolve?

Comment: You are doing exactly what this answer suggests you NOT do.  Just start over with a fresh install, and you will have everything you need (don't copy old folders into new!)

Comment: I already tried to download other SDKs but didn't work. I resolved finally by using Android Studio, Eclipse is too buggy (I thought I'd never say this) for updates.